# Cacls error when assigning user rights

Tags: windows, vbscript, rights, ownership, cacls

Can anyone tell me why this command fails with:
"The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect."

cacls c:\TestHome\brytest\JBryan42 /t /c /g JBryan42:F

While this command succeeds:

cacls c:\TestHome\brytest\JBryan42 /t /c /g Administrator:F

They both show the "processed dir: c:\TestHome\brytest\JBryan42" but for JBryan42, the error comes up after that.

This is on Windows 7, logged in as the Administrator.

My goal is to give full rights and ownership to JBryan42 (The user exists and is non-admin).

Can anyone give me a clue here? What am I missing? Why can't Windows have "chown"?

Comment: Have you tried using icacls instead?

Comment: I'd love to ... but my customer wants me to use cacls only.

Comment: I think that trying icacls might still give you useful information, even if you can't use it in your final production code.  Is this a problem you can replicate, or is it just one particular computer that's having trouble with it?  What are the existing permissions on the directory in question?

Comment: Advise your customer to drop `cacls`. It does not handle inheritance correctly. `icacls` does. It also does allow you to take ownership of objects (like `chown`).

Comment: I was wrong about there not being a command to assign ownership of a file to someone else.  As Ansgar points out, `icacls` allows this, provided you run it with admin privilege.  So `icacls /setowner` is the Windows equivalent of `chown`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its best to give access without ownership? Is this not a feasible solution? I would guess you would replace the /g with /p instead?